# Ansible playbook - unzip to specific (renamed directory

Tags: ansible

I have ansible playbook which extract tar archive

```
- name: Unarchive Installation
    become: yes
    unarchive:
       src: "/opt/dist-{{ version }}.tar"
       dest: /opt/
       remote_src: yes
    when: inventory_hostname == ip_address
```

oap_version differs, so differs extracted folder name, format of extracted folder is always `oa-{{ version }}-some_number`

Depending of oap-version, number after `-` is different, so it breaks next block, entering into extracted directory and installing package.

```
- name: Run Installation
    become: yes
    command: 'python install.py --modules="Platform" --username admin --password pass --repo-base-url="http://download.com/oa/{{ version }}/repo"'
    args:
       chdir: /opt/oa-{{ version }}-1234/
```

Is there any way to specify custom destination folder name, or for ansible to find out number after `oap-version` and store it into variable, or to register destination and pass it to variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [How to tell what directory was created by ansible's unarchive module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576449/how-to-tell-what-directory-was-created-by-ansibles-unarchive-module)

```
- name: Unarchive Installation
    become: yes
    unarchive:
       src: "/opt/dist-{{ version }}.tar"
       dest: /opt/
      remote_src: yes
       list_files: yes
    when: inventory_hostname == ip_address
    register: archive_contents
```

and for entering into that directory:

```
- name: Run Installation
    become: yes
    command: 'python install.py --modules="Platform" --username admin --password password --repo-base-url="http://download.com/oa/{{ version }}/repo"'
    args:
       chdir: "/opt/{{ archive_contents.files[0] }}"
    when: inventory_hostname == ip_address
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Find out number after oap-version and store it into a variable."*

A: Given the tarball

```
$ tar tvf test.tar.gz 
drwxrwxr-x vlado/vlado       0 2019-10-30 12:29 oa-version.0.99-3256/
-rw-rw-r-- vlado/vlado       0 2019-10-30 12:29 oa-version.0.99-3256/02
-rw-rw-r-- vlado/vlado       0 2019-10-30 12:29 oa-version.0.99-3256/01
-rw-rw-r-- vlado/vlado       0 2019-10-30 12:29 oa-version.0.99-3256/03
```

The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    my_version: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'tar tvf test.tar.gz').splitlines().0.split(' ')[-1].split('-')[-1][:-1] }}"
- debug:
    var: my_version
```

give

```
"my_version": "3256"
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, i just found out another way.